# How can I make the CircleAvatar to change color when it is clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: c]

I tried the other solutions that were published here in StackOverflow, but they didn't work. Any suggestion? `

Widget _method(String day) {

```
return InkWell(
  child: new Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      radius: 16.0,
      child: Text(day,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontFamily: 'Product-Sans',
          )),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {

    });
  }
);
```

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plugins that can do this for you but if you want to learn it from scratch:

Basically, you keept a variable `_currentSelectedIndex` that keeps track of the currently selected tile. When the user presses on that tile, you call `setState` and update the current tile. You can then configure the color of the selected and non selected tiles.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Weekday selector',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentSelectedIndex;

  final Map<int, String> _weekdayIndices = {
    0: 'S',
    1: 'M',
    2: 'T',
    3: 'W',
    4: 'T',
    5: 'F',
    6: 'S',
  };

  Widget _weekdayTile(int index) {
    bool selected = index == _currentSelectedIndex;

    Color tileColor = selected ? Colors.red : Colors.white;
    Color textColor = selected ? Colors.white : Colors.black;

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _currentSelectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: tileColor,
          radius: 16.0,
          child: Text(
            _weekdayIndices[index],
            style: TextStyle(
              color: textColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _weekdayPicker() {
    List<Widget> tiles = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      tiles.add(_weekdayTile(i));
    }

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: tiles,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _weekdayPicker(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [weekdays](https://pub.dev/packages/weekdays). Here you can also get date also for current week.